# [Classname::class,'methodName']

Tags: php, laravel

Empezando con Laravel encontré esta forma de llamar a un método estático dentro de una ruta

```html
Route::get(
    '/user/profile',
    [UserProfileController::class, 'show']
)->name('profile');
```

¿Cuál es el nombre de esta forma de llamar a un método estático? ¿es azúcar sintáctica? ¿sólo se pueden llamar de esa manera a los métodos de clase estáticos?

Comment: Supongo que te referis a `Route`, es una una [Facade](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/facades#main-content), son muy usadas en laravel. Podes leer mas en la doc  > *proporciona una sintaxis concisa y memorizable que te permite utilizar las funciones de Laravel...*

Comment: El ruteo de Laravel implementa [*Llamadas de Retorno*](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.types.callable.php#language.types.callable.passing); una de sus formas es con un arreglo, donde el índice 0 es el nombre de la clase y el índice 1 es el nombre de un método estático.

Answer (score 0):

Esa forma de nombrar es para que luego puedas usar la función;

`route('nombre_de_la_ruta');`

O sea que;

- **Route::get** = Obtienes mediante GET
- **'/user/profile'** = URI
- **UserProfileController::class** = Controlador ( **UserProfileController.blade.php** )
- **'show'** = Función dentro del controlador ( **public function show(){...** )
- **name** = Nombre interno para facilitar.

Yo también estoy empezando, hace unos dias..

Saludos